# delphi seattle - editor: ctrl+V not working

Tags: delphi, windows-8, copy-paste, code-editor, delphi-10-seattle

**Background:** I am developing programs on Windows8 [64-bit] with Delphi Seattle Enterprise (target O/S: Windows). I just upgraded from Delphi XE4.

**Problem:** While writing code in the Delphi editor, CTRL+V to paste text isn't working - i.e. nothing is pasted.

**What I tried so far (besides researching this situation on the Web - without success):**

1. Ctrl+C & Ctrl+V do work in other applications (Delphi XE4, Word, Notepad++, etc).
2. Performing CTRL+C in Delphi then pasting that text in other programs (Word, Notepad++) using CTRL+V works fine. This suggests that the Clipboard can be successfully written to while copying.
3. In Delphi, I have tried to use the menu *Edit...Copy* & *Edit...Paste* options instead of the CTRL+C / CTRL+V keys - same result: no pasting.
4. Delphi Editor settings: Insert Mode and Overwrite Blocks are both checked. Key Mappings is set to Default.

**My Question:** What am I missing? Is this a new behaviour in Delphi Seattle?

Thanks.

Comment: Ctrl+V works fine in Seattle for me. I tested with File->New->Other->Console application, selected the `try..finally` block that's automatically created, Ctrl+C to copy, inserted a new line just before the final `end.` of the file, and Ctrl+V to paste,which worked fine. I repeated the Ctrl+V four more times, and ended up with four more copies of the block inserted just as you'd expect.

Comment: I did some more testing: Turns out that **CTRL-V stops working if a Web browser is open** at the same time as Delphi 10 (I tried with both I.E 10 and FireFox 39) . As soon as there is no browser open, CTRL+V works again (no need to re-start Delphi!). Other program (Word, Sybase Central, Notepad++) don't cause any problems. Very strange and VERY counter-productive.

Comment: I have Firefox 40.0.3 open (and had it open when testing - I read your question). This seems like an issue of some sort with your system, rather than an issue with Delphi.

Comment: I tried having Delphi XE4 and Delphi 10 open side-by-side while IE10 is open.

Comment: Then I selected some text in D10 but could not paste it in D10; however, pasting it in XE4 worked fine. Still investigating the problem...

Comment: Appears to be environmental

Comment: I agree, and it seems to be a combination of factors: DXE4 has no trouble with any of this. The moment I start a browser, DX loses its paste functionality (other programs aren't affected at all). Then I can only reboot to regain the ability to Paste.

Answer (score 0):

Two thoughts.

Try killing the rdpclip.exe process.
Run a malware scan.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be an rdlclip.exe process running at any time (as listed by the Task Manager). I have a full system scan scheduled (WebRoot) every day and nothing has popped-up on that front.

Answer (score 0):

Oddly, when Delphi starts acting up like this, pressing CTRL-C 3 times does allow a subsequent paste (CTRL-V).